# web service error: operation with parameters cannot be found

Tags: c#, web-services, coldfusion

I am trying to consume the .net webservice from cold fusion. Methods having simple types working fine. But i am having problems with one particular method which accepts byte[] array as input.

Below the sample webmethod declaration

```
   [WebMethod]
   public AVStatus ScanStream(byte[] fileObject)
    {
              // code
    }
```

and the cold fusion code consuming this service is

```
   <cffile action="readBinary"   file="#FileName#" variable="filedata">
   <cfset b64file = #toBase64(filedata)#>
   <cfinvoke webservice =  "http://xxx/scanservice.asmx?wsdl" 
      method = "ScanStream"      
      returnVariable = "result">
           <cfinvokeargument name="fileObject" value="#b64file#" />

   </cfinvoke>
```

This always leads to this error **Web service operation ScanStream with parameters cannot be found**.

can someone help me out this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that the binary data has been exposed as `bas64` string in the coldfusion while `byte[]` is exposed by the service as an XML array (of bytes).

Change the `ScanStream` (if you can) to accept a string, if web service is not yours you could convince owners to provide another method which accepts string and uses `Convert.FromBase64String` to change to byte array.

Answer (score 0):

Webservices are remote, not public.  Public allows access by other CF classes and pages.  Change public to remote, and you should be able to "see" your webservice.